# ошибка: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord.py

Создаю голосового бота.
При запуске данной команды в консоль выдаётся ошибка

> Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

```
@voice.command()
async def setup(self, ctx):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('voice.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    guildID = ctx.guild.id
    id = ctx.author.id
    if ctx.author.id == ctx.guild.owner.id or ctx.author.id == 151028268856770560:
        def check(m):
            return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
        await ctx.channel.send("**Настройка будет длиться 60 секунд**")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"**Введите желаемое название для категории:(пример: Приватные Каналы)**")
        try:
            category = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout = 60.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.channel.send('Время ответа истекло!')
        else:
            new_cat = await ctx.guild.create_category_channel(category.content)
            await ctx.channel.send('**Введите желаемое имя для канала: (пример: Нажми для создания)**')
            try:
                channel = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout = 60.0)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.channel.send('Время ответа истекло!')
            else:
                try:
                    channel = await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(channel.content, category=new_cat)
                    c.execute("SELECT * FROM guild WHERE guildID = ? AND ownerID=?", (guildID, id))
                    voice=c.fetchone()
                    if voice is None:
                        c.execute ("INSERT INTO guild VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(guildID,id,channel.id,new_cat.id))
                    else:
                        c.execute ("UPDATE guild SET guildID = ?, ownerID = ?, voiceChannelID = ?, voiceCategoryID = ? WHERE guildID = ?",(guildID,id,channel.id,new_cat.id, guildID))
                    await ctx.channel.send("**Настройка прошла успешно, голосовой канал установлен!**")
                except:
                    await ctx.channel.send("Вы некорректно ввели названия \nИспользуйте `.voice setup` для перезапуска настройки!")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Ня, только создатель данного сервера может произвести настройку данного бота!")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникнет, если запустить команду не на сервере (тогда `ctx.guild` будет `None`). Возможно и в других ситуациях, можно будет сказать точнее, если знать, на какой строчке возникает ошибка.